# Android scale animation on a textview causes text to move

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation defined as

scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
          android:fromXScale="1.0"
          android:fromYScale="1.0"
          android:toXScale="2.0"
          android:toYScale="2.0"
          android:duration="3000">        
    </scale>
</set>
```

Which is added programmatically, via

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.playresultPopupYardsTextView);
Animation scale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
scale.setStartOffset(5000);
scale.setFillAfter(true);
tv2.clearAnimation();
tv2.setAnimation(scale);
```

pw is a PopupWindow defined as

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(view.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                
            final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
               inflater.inflate(R.layout.playresult_popup, null, false), 
               700, 
               300, 
               true);
```

The layout is as follows
playresult_popup.xl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CC667788"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playresultPopupPlaysTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text=""
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Yards Gained"
    />        


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playresultPopupYardsTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text=""
    />        

</LinearLayout>
```

When the scale animation runs it scales the text as expected, but each step of the way moves towards the right of the popup window.  I'm wondering if this is because I don't declare a pivot point - if so, how to I get the proper pivot point to use so that the text stays in place, just scales in size?

I've searched, but haven't been able to find an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out. I did not realize that you can use percentage values for the pivot point. Adding pivotX="50%" and pivotY="50%" solved this. So:

```
<scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="2.0"
       android:toYScale="2.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="3000">
</scale>
```